# Convert python byte "array" to int "array

Tags: python

This is my first code in python and I have this issue:

I'm reading a binary file as:

```
def read_file(file):
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        frame = f.read()
        print(type(frame)) #out = <class 'bytes'>
        return frame
```

I need to convert all the vector to int values instead using them as bytes.

After printing I get something like this:

```
print(frame[0:10])
b'\xff\xff\xff\xffXabccc'
```

However if I print passing one position only I get this:(the integer values are correct, but I just get them using the function print)

```
print(frame[0])
255    
print(frame[1])
255
print(frame[2])
255
print(frame[3])
255
print(frame[4])
88
print(frame[5])
97
print(frame[6])
98
print(frame[7])
99
print(frame[8])
99
print(frame[9])
99
print(frame[10])
98
```

The question is: How can I convert all the positions of my array in one step? I would like to run the code

```
print(frame[0:10])
```

and get something like

```
[255, 255, 255, 255, 88, 97, 98, 99 ,99, 99, 98]
```

Comment: FWIW, `frame` is __not__ a `bytearray`, but a `bytes` object. Both exist in Python, but whereas the former is mutable, your `bytes` object is not.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Note: this solution only works for Python 3. For Python 2 solution please see Scott Hunter's answer.**

You could do this using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [1]: frame = b'\xff\xff\xff\xffXabccc'

In [2]: int_values = [x for x in frame]

In [3]: print(int_values)
[255, 255, 255, 255, 88, 97, 98, 99, 99, 99]
```

To confirm that these are indeed stored as integer values which you can work with:

```
In [4]: print([type(x) for x in int_values])
[<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, 
<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>]
```

Comment: Note: only works in Python 3 (Python 2 gives list of characters).

Answer (score 13):

The simplest, and most obvious way to do it, is to pass the `frame` object to the list constructor. No list comprehension is needed for this:

```
>>> frame = b'\xff\xff\xff\xffXabccc'
>>> list(frame)
[255, 255, 255, 255, 88, 97, 98, 99, 99, 99]
```

Comment: Note: only works in Python 3 (Python 2 gives list of characters).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a list of integer values, and not just print them, you could use:

```
[ord(x) for x in frame]
```

Comment: Note: only works in Python 2 (Python 3 throws TypeError).

Answer (score 2):

One solution for python2 or 3 is:

```
list(bytearray(frame))
```